# How do I print specific lines of a file in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to print everything in a file with python. But, whenever I use python's built-in readfile() function it only print the first line of my text file. Here's my code:

```
File = open("test.txt", 'r', 0)
line = File.readline()[:]
print line
```

and thank you for everyone that answers

and to make my question clearer every time I run the code it prints only "word list food

Comment: You can use File.readlines() to read all lines of the file as a list.

Comment: So... did you want the question in the title answered, or the question in the body?

Comment: If Zabari's answer is correct, you should accept it with the green check-sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File.readlines()
```

will, as emre. said, return a list of all the lines in your file.  If you'd like to produce a similar result using the readline() command,

```
s=File.readline()
while s!="":
   print s
   s=File.readline()
```

Both methods above leave a newline at the end of each string, except for the last string.

Another alternative would be:

```
for s in File:
    print s
```

To search for a specific string, or a specific line number, I'd say the first method is best.  Looking for a specific line number would be as simple as:

```
File.readlines()[i]
```

Where i is the line number you are interested in accessing.  Looking for a string is a bit more work, but looping through the list would not be too challenging.  Something like:

```
L=File.readlines()
s="yourStringHere"
i=0

while i<len(L):
   if L[i].find(s)!=-1:
     break
   i+=1
print i
```

would give you the line number that contained the string you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
printline = 6
lineCounter = 0
with open('anyTxtFile.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lineCounter += 1
        if lineCounter == printline:
            print(line, end='')
```

Opens text file, in working directory, and prints printLine

Answer (score 0):

Make it more pythonic.

```py
print_line = 6
with open('input_txt_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == print_line:
            print(line, end='')
            break
```